# Move to 2 Django physical servers (front and backend) from a single production server?

Tags: django

I currently have a growing Django production server that has all of the front end and backend services running on it.  I could keep growing that server larger and larger, but instead I want to try and leave that main server as my backend server and create multiple front end servers that would run apache/nginx and remotely connect to the main production backend server.

I'm using slicehost now, so I don't think I can benefit from having the multiple servers run on an intranet.  How do I do this?

Comment: What is the source of your servers' load?  Is it CPU?  Database?  Disk?  Multiple apache/nginx front end servers makes less sense than a single apache/nginx front end and multiple backend servers, so is there another problem at foot?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing what you're already doing and how it isn't working out.

Answer (score 1):

The first step in scaling your server is usually to separate the database server. I'm assuming this is all you meant by "backend services", unless you give us any more details.

All this needs is a change to your settings file. Change DATABASE_HOST from localhost to the new IP of your database server.

If your site is heavy on static content, creating a separate media server could help. You may even look into a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

Answer (score 1):

The first step usually is to separate the server running actual Python code and the database server. Any background jobs that does processing would probably run on the database server. I assume that when you say front end server, you actually mean a server running Python code.

Now, as every request will have to do a number of database queries, latency between the webserver and the database server is very important. I don't know if Slicehost has some feature to allow you to create two virtual machines that are "close" in terms of network latency(a quick google search did not find anything). They seem like nice guys, so maybe you could ask them if they have such a service or could make an exception.

Anyway, when you do have two machines on Slicehost, you could check the latency between them by simply pinging between them. When you have the result you will probably know if this is at all feasible or not.

Further steps depends on your application. If it is media heavy, then maybe using a separate media server would make sense. Otherwise the normal step is to add more web servers.

--

As a side note, I personally think it makes more sense to invest in real dedicated servers with dedicated network equipment for this kind of setup. This of course depends on what budget you are on.

I would also suggest looking into Amazon EC2 where you can provision servers that are magically close to each other.